# Upload Video Android server error 404

Tags: android, web-services, post, video, upload

I'm trying to upload the video via webservice created by me in Java. Sometimes sends the video as well but sometimes the server returns "400 error, the parameters are wrong"

Did you guys can help me?

```
    private class SendVideoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            final String url = server_url + "/rest/cloud/uploadFilePost";
            Form form = new Form();
            form.add("test_id", test_id);
            form.add("report_id", report_id);

            String encoded_file = cc.encodeFileToBase64Binary(mediaFile);
            form.add("encoded_file", encoded_file);
            String resp = "";
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createSystem();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test_id", test_id));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("report_id", String
                    .valueOf(report_id)));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("encoded_file",
                    encoded_file));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            try {

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {

                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    try {

                        resp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    } finally {
                        instream.close();
                    }

                }

            } finally {
                response.close();
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }

            return resp;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("VideoAsyncTask (Background)", e.getMessage(), e);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The webservice java

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/cloud/uploadFilePost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadPostVideo(
        @RequestParam(value = "test_id") String test_id,
        @RequestParam(value = "report_id") String report_id,
        @RequestParam(value = "encoded_file") String encoded_file) {

    String output = "";

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.vodafone.webmobiletestingsuite");

    byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded_file);

    String file_name = "Video" + report_id + ".mp4";

    try {

        File file = new File(file_name);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        fos.write(bytes);

        fos.close();

        log.info("Starting post cloud");

        cloudbo = new CloudBO();

        output = cloudbo.uploadFile(report_id, file);

        log.info("FILE PATH: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        boolean r = file.delete();

        log.info("DELETE: " + r);

        log.info("Finish post cloud");

        UsabilityReport ur = boUsabilityReports.findById(
                Integer.parseInt(report_id), UsabilityReport.class);

        log.info("Start attachment");

        log.info("REPORT ID:" + ur.getExecutionReportId());

        CameraAttachment ca = new CameraAttachment();

        ca.setPublicURL(output.split(";")[1]);

        log.info("PUBLIC URL:" + output.split(";")[1]);

        ca.setUsability_report(ur);

        log.info("Finish attachment");

        boCameraAttachments.create(ca);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        output = "filenotfound_exception";

    } catch (IOException e) {

        output = "io_exception";

    } catch (DbxException e) {

        output = "Dbx: " + e.toString();

    }

    responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS");
    responseHeaders.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(output, responseHeaders,
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: You have provided a lot of code and little in the way of what you have tried.  A good question tries to minimize the amount of "code review" a responder needs to wade through and tries to get to the heart of the matter.  Is this really the smallest code that illustrates the issue?

Comment: Yes you right. I just simplify my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is from your server end. try using the MultipartFile class in spring. here is a simple tutorial that can help http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-tutorial-single-and-multiple-files

Comment: but what is the different i have to make in android client?

Comment: i sent files by converting to bitmap using SystemUtils.decodeFile(filePath) then i converted to ByteArrayOutputStream, got the byte array and appended to my entity like this entity.addPart(fileName, contentBody)